# How to fetch users data by date from date to date in spring boot java code

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

Actually,my doubt is i have the users list will many other parameters now i want to filter the data according to from date and to date(monthly),Could someone please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Streams to filter data.

```
userList.stream().filter(user -> {
  if(user.getDate() >= fromDate && user.getDate() <=toDate){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: dhruv tailor  i got the users data from azure aad using token,Now i am trying to get users data in a filtered way using from and to dates.So that when user hits api it will give me json of that from and to date

Answer (score 0):

Entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    Long id;
    @CreationTimestamp
    Date date;
}
```

Repository

```
public interface  UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAllByOrderByDate();
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserService{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAllByOrderByDate();
    List<User> userList= new ArrayList<>();
    for(User user: users){
        if(user.getDate >= fromDate && user.getDate() <=toDate ){
                userList.add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Zishan i got the users data from azure aad using token,Now i am trying to get users data in a filtered way using from and to dates.So that when user hits api it will give me json of that from and to date